# Solving for Angle-side-side triangle in simplest radical form

Tags: triangles, angle

Assuming Capital letters are angles, opposite legs are lower case

> In triangle $XYZ$, $\cos X = 1/2,$ $\cos Y = -1/4$ and $x =6$. Find $y$ in simplest radical form.

So far I have been using $\cos$ (adj/hyp) to create a possible ratio, but as you see am having trouble with the negative. Any pointers?

[image]

Comment: Triangle $XYZ$ is not a right triangle. In fact, you know that angle $Y$ must be obtuse. Just solve it as you would solve any triangle where you know one side and all angles.

Comment: Since this is not a right triangle, you cannot use "cos=(adj/hyp)" directly.

Comment: Are you looking for $Y$ or for $y$? Angle or length?

Comment: looking for y side length

Comment: @HarryIguana Then you should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4354640/edit) the question and change "*find Y*" to "*find y*". You already got an answer to the question about the angle, not the side, because that's how you posted it.

Comment: hmm i see. Thought i put lower case y. My intention in the image was to shade in upper case Y, but now i fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints/general facts that will help you solve for $\sin Y$ exactly and without using a calculator:

- Pythagorean Theorem:  $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$.
- For $0^\circ < \theta < 180^\circ$, $0< \sin \theta <1 $.
- For $0^\circ < \theta < 180^\circ$, $\cos \theta <0 \;$ (i.e. $\cos \theta$ is negative) if and only if $\; 90^\circ < \theta < 180^\circ$.

Once you know $\sin Y$ you can use the information about whether $Y$ is acute or obtuse and the $\sin^{-1}$ function to say what the measure of angle $Y$ is exactly.

Beware, there may be more information than you need/distractors in the problem as it is described.

Answer (score 0):

I have entered my work here, this I believe should be the right answer. Confirmation please

Also is this the right way to format? $\cos^{1/2}$  ?

$X = \cos^{-1}(1/2)$,        $Y = \cos^{-1}(-1/4)$

$X=60$, $Y= 104.4$ ($q1,q2$)

$\frac{\sin60}{60} = \sin104.4/y$, $y = 6\sin104.4/\sin60$

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: This is hard to follow if you do not consistently capitalize $Y$ for angles vs. $y$ for sides. Also, `y = 6.71` is an approximation, not the "*simplest radical form*". For that, you need to calculate $\sin Y$ directly, not using an approximation of $\arccos$.

Comment: check edits? Like that?